# block layout message missing buttons

Tags: slack-api

I created a slash command that returns a nicely formatted block-layout message.  It essentially has a couple of sections with images inside.  However, while the message can be displayed properly, the usual buttons (emoji reaction, create thread, etc.) are missing.  The only available action is "Delete Message".

Is this the proper behavior? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you share the code you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons were missing because I was posting to my own personal channel.